# NewtonSoft - Converting JSON to an Object

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm trying to write a JSON file to an Object.
This is how I'm creating the JSON file.

```
                var ActiveCustomer = new Customer(userID, fName, lName, pNumber, sLocation);
                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ActiveCustomer, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
                using (StreamWriter file = File.CreateText(curFile))
                {
                    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                    serializer.Serialize(file, json);
                }
                Console.WriteLine(json);
```

I've read the documentation, and this is the closest I am getting to creating an object from it:

```
                var ReadFromFile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Customer>(File.ReadAllText(curFile));
                Console.WriteLine(ReadFromFile);
```

It prints out the string, and then includes a long error saying this it cannot convert a string to an object.

CUSTOMER CLASS::

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
namespace Project0.Lib
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public string _CustomerID { get; set; }
        public string _FirstName { get; set; }
        public string _LastName { get; set; }
        public string _PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string _StoreLocation { get; set; }
        public Customer()
        {

        }
        public Customer(string customerID, string firstName, string lastName, string phonenumber,string storelocation)
        {
            this._CustomerID = customerID;
            this._FirstName = firstName;
            this._LastName = lastName;
            this._PhoneNumber = phonenumber;
            this._StoreLocation = storelocation;
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return _CustomerID + " " + _FirstName + " " + _LastName + " " + _PhoneNumber + " " + _StoreLocation;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share the ``Customer`` class?

Comment: in this line ``serializer.Serialize(file, json)`` you serialize a serialized object. in this line change ``json`` by ``ActiveCustomer `` like : ``serializer.Serialize(file, ActiveCustomer )`` Or use @Slipoch solution.

Answer (score 0):

Stick a try/catch around the code deserialising the string, also get the string out to a variable first and while running, break on that and check out what the string 'looks' like, make sure the json string is correct, I have previously had an issue where parameter names were inside single speech marks ' instead of double "

One area I saw that the issue may occur in your code (it may mess up the string) is:

```
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ActiveCustomer, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
            using (StreamWriter file = File.CreateText(curFile))
            {
                JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                serializer.Serialize(file, json);
            }
```

In this you are serialising an object (fine), but then you use a jsonserializer to serialise it again? This would mean it won't match the Customer object class. Instead of that maybe just write the json string to a file, so:

```
 string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ActiveCustomer, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
 File.WriteAllText(file, json);
```

https://json.org/example.html may help.

If this does not work, could you please edit your post to include the JSON string?